# 404 Not Found after CNAME change

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cname

The following website works as I want it to:

http://correctproject.be/

This is a new website made for a company that used to have another domain.
So we asked if the old domain could be forwarded with CNAME. So they did..

[image]

But when I try to access the site through the new adres (http://www.correctvastgoed.be), I get a 404.

[image]

Can anyone help me on my way to find the solution? Can it be a problem in my htaccess?

Comment: How are you hosting the site? Are you using domain-based virtual hosting?

Comment: They did the CNAME 3 hours ago

Comment: i'm hosting the site on a one.com server (correctproject.be) but have no control over the correctvastgoed.be domain

Comment: _How_ are you hosting it? Is the site dependent on the domain name, e.g. using [name-based virtual hosts in Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)?

Comment: hmm i'm not sure, how can i find that out? (sorry for my lack of knowledge)

Comment: It's hitting the correct IP (Remote Address: 46.30.213.103:80), so you probably need to make sure that domain name is listed as an alias in your Apache/nginx/IIS configuration

Comment: That depends entirely on what your host exposes to you. Do you have SSH access? Root access? A web-based panel? Do you make changes via email requests? In all of these cases you might see something attaching a domain name to your site. You may need to add the other domain to the site.

Comment: What is the CNAME name you have put? CNAME names needs to be @ to mirror the entire site

Comment: Thanks aynber for the help, i'll go find out how I have to do that on a one.com server

Comment: @aynber , in the one.com control panel I can only add aliases like [hostname].correctproject.be but not with another domain

Comment: @Chris, i have no SSH access, only root, but i have complete control over the control panel in One.com

Comment: @DonnieAshok I didn't put the CNAME myself, but I'm pretty sure they did it allright

Comment: You may have to contact One.com to find out how to add another domain as an alias, instead of a subdomain. Otherwise you're going to need a service that will do a 301 redirect for your correctvastgoed.be domain to correctproject.be

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the solution, I'm gonna post it when it is working, this is a one.com problem with the account I think, i'll keep you posted

Comment: thanks all for the help so far!